# Dois selects com o mesmo script

Tags: javascript, html-select

Possuo um select que utiliza um script para preencher o campo de cidades, por meio do estado selecionado.
O problema é que preciso adicionar outro select e quando adiciono, somente um select funciona.

```html
<script src="http://cidades-estados-js.googlecode.com/files/cidades-estados-v0.2.js"></script>

<select id="estado" name="estado"></select>

    <select id="cidade" name="cidade"></select>
    <br/>
    <select id="estado1" name="estado1"></select>

    <select id="cidade1" name="cidade1"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
        new dgCidadesEstados(document.getElementById('estado'), document.getElementById('cidade'), true);
      }
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
        new dgCidadesEstados(document.getElementById('estado1'), document.getElementById('cidade1'), true);
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: @renan possuo 2 selects onde seleciono o estado, e ao selecionar o estado, seleciono as cidades daquele estado. Porém ao adicionar o segundo, somente UM funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa criar duas funções `window.onload` basta utilizar uma, e dentro dela utilizar um outro `new dgCidadesEstados`...

---

Muito provavelmente só estava sendo lido um `onLoad` na criação do formulário, por isso não carregava o outro `select`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  new dgCidadesEstados(document.getElementById('estado'), document.getElementById('cidade'), true);
  new dgCidadesEstados(document.getElementById('estado1'), document.getElementById('cidade1'), true);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cidades-estados-js.googlecode.com/files/cidades-estados-v0.2.js"></script>
  <select id="estado" name="estado"></select>
  <select id="cidade" name="cidade"></select><br/><br/>
  <select id="estado1" name="estado1"></select>
  <select id="cidade1" name="cidade1"></select>
```

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente isso.